# How to compare 2 tables and merge the duplicate entities in a field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to compare 2 tables then merge the duplicate entities in a field after comparing two tables in mysql?

Example:

If I have

```
TBL_SCHEDULE                   TBL_ORDER

ID   CUS_ID    DATE            ID   CUS_ID  ORDER ID
-------------------            -----------------------
1    1      2016-12-11         1     1      1
2    1      2016-12-11         2     3      10
3    3      2016-12-11         3     3      34
4    3      2016-12-11         4     1      2
5    7      2016-12-11         5     7      11
6    4      2016-12-11         6     7      15
```

I want to achieve this result:

```
CUS_ID
------
1
3
7
```

I just want to catch the matching cus_id's between two tables and merge them. TIA

Comment: You should show what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do a `JOIN`. Do `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates:

```
select distinct s.CUS_ID
from TBL_SCHEDULE s
join TBL_ORDER o on s.CUS_ID = o.CUS_ID
```

Alternatively you can use `INTERSECT` - if supported by MySQL:

```
select CUS_ID from TBL_SCHEDULE
intersect
select CUS_ID from TBL_ORDER
```

Comment: How can I combine that two queries at once? TIA

Comment: Just use one of them. Each one will give you the wanted result. (I like the INTERSECT query, but I'm not sure it works with MySQL.)

Answer (score 0):

Do a full join on ID and CUS_ID, then check values of CUS_ID where TBL_SCHEDULE.CUS_ID and TBL_ORDER.CUS_ID is null.